# How do I un-link the selection of two separate comboboxes which bind to the same object?

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext, selectionchanged

I have two seperate WPF Comboboxes both of them bind to the same object to populate their values. However, when I change the selection in one combobox, the selection in the other combobox is changed to the same as the first, and vice versa. This is not the behavior I want, I want only want to bind the content of the comboboxes to a single source without mirroring their selections. I am binding to a BindingList.To bind I use

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

and

```
comboBox1.DataContext = bindingList;
```

What do I need to do to unlink the selections of these two comboboxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way these actually work bind the scenes is by wrapping the collection in an instance of `ICollectionView`, which maintains the current selected item (amongst other things).

To get the behaviour you want, just set the DataContext of each combo box to:

```
new ListCollectionView(bindingList);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! ListCollectionView allows CollectionChanged events to propagate from the original object which is perfect.